tlrc not working with homebrew on mac for unknown reasona
I installed the package using brew install as indicated in READ.me with no caveats, then installed rust because it was a missing dependency, and the command tlrc is not recognised still. Here's the output of brew info and use of the command:
brew info tlrc
==> tlrc: stable 1.9.3 (bottled), HEAD
Official tldr client written in Rust
https://github.com/tldr-pages/tlrc
Conflicts with:
  tealdeer (because both install `tldr` binaries)
  tldr (because both install `tldr` binaries)
Installed
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tlrc/1.9.3 (12 files, 2.3MB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2024-12-14 at 09:50:31
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/t/tlrc.rb
License: MIT
==> Dependencies
Build: rust ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
zsh completions have been installed to:
  /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Analytics
install: 456 (30 days), 1,420 (90 days), 7,478 (365 days)
install-on-request: 456 (30 days), 1,420 (90 days), 7,478 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
❯ tlrc h
zsh: correct 'tlrc' to 'tr' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: tlrc

rust has been properly installed:
brew info rust
==> rust: stable 1.83.0 (bottled), HEAD
Safe, concurrent, practical language
https://www.rust-lang.org/
Installed
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rust/1.83.0 (3,552 files, 312.8MB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2024-12-14 at 09:56:51
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/r/rust.rb
License: Apache-2.0 OR MIT
==> Dependencies
Required: libgit2 ✔, libssh2 ✔, llvm ✔, openssl@3 ✔, pkgconf ✔, zstd ✔
==> Requirements
Required: macOS >= 10.12 (or Linux) ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
zsh completions have been installed to:
  /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Analytics
install: 38,074 (30 days), 106,686 (90 days), 460,024 (365 days)
install-on-request: 28,723 (30 days), 80,606 (90 days), 344,330 (365 days)
build-error: 248 (30 days)


The command is called tldr.  This was hinted at in the Conflicts with section of the brew info output that you posted.
It is also shown in the output of brew list tlrc:
% brew list tlrc
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tlrc/1.9.3/.crates.toml
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tlrc/1.9.3/.crates2.json
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tlrc/1.9.3/bin/tldr
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tlrc/1.9.3/etc/bash_completion.d/tldr
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tlrc/1.9.3/sbom.spdx.json
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tlrc/1.9.3/share/fish/vendor_completions.d/tldr.fish
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tlrc/1.9.3/share/man/man1/tldr.1
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tlrc/1.9.3/share/zsh/site-functions/_tldr

Note the /opt/homebrew/Cellar/tlrc/1.9.3/bin/tldr entry.  This is automatically linked to the Homebrew bin directory upon installation, and should therefore be in your path.
% type -a tldr
tldr is /opt/homebrew/bin/tldr

You should not need to install Rust to use tldr.  You would only need Rust installed if you need to re-build the binary, in which case Homebrew would install it for you (it's a build dependency, not a run-time dependency).
